# My web cam is not working

Tags: webcam

My web cam device has suddenly stopped working without any reason. Even it worked some days ago. Its saying that, "**no device found**". What should i do ?

I'm currently using Acer Aspire 5100 Notebook.

Comment: Please expand upon the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a hardware failure, you can troubleshoot it with Ubuntu Live USB. Plug in the live usb and checkout the webcam, if the problem still persist then it is probably due to the hardware failure.
Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say - check the plugin but that's so obvious. Maybe also check it on some other computer to make sure it is working. You can also try to mount it manually.

Comment: _"Maybe also check it on some other computer to make sure it is working."_ It looks like he has a built in webcam.